# delete all new lines '\n' between two intances of a pattern, to combine them into a sentence. Using sed or awk

Tags: awk, sed

I have this input file as input.txt as shown below
In the output
I am trying to delete all new lines between the all occurances of pattern '------'.
Then delete that pattern from the output file
print_me(0034 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.)
and insert a new line with string containing the number, such as
printername('0034')

input.txt

```
print_me 0034 bla bla bla bla bl
              a bla bla bla bla.
------ -------------------------
print_me 0035 bla bla bla bla bl
              a bla bla bla bla.
------ -------------------------
print_me 0037 bla bla bla bla bl
              a bla bla bla bla.
------ -------------------------
print_me 0038 bla bla bla bla bl
              a bla bla bla bla.
------ -------------------------
```

desired output.txt

```
    printername('0034')
    print_me(0034 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.)
    printername('0035')
    print_me(0035 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.)
    printername('0036')
    print_me(0036 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.)
    printername('0037')
    print_me(0037 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.)
    printername('0038')
    print_me(0038 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.)
```

The output I get implementing answer1 is as:

```
printername('0034')
print_me(0034 bla bla bla bla b  la bla bla bla bla.   )
printername('0035')
print_me(0035 bla bla bla bla b  la bla bla bla bla.   )
printername('0036')
print_me(0036 bla bla bla bla b  la bla bla bla bla.   )
printername('0037')
print_me(0037 bla bla bla bla b  la bla bla bla bla.   )
printername('0038')
print_me(0038 bla bla bla bla b  la bla bla bla bla.   )
```

So now how can I improve the code to remove the extra tabs and combine any number of lines between the patterns, and have them read as one sentence within the brackets of print_me(bla bla bla bla+ bla = bla +/- bla) - example

input2.txt

```
print_me 0034 bla bla bla bla bl
              a bla bla bla bla.
------ -------------------------
print_me 0035 bla bla bla bla bl
              a bla bla bla bla-
              a bla bla bla bla.
------ -------------------------
print_me 0037 bla bla bla__la bl
              a bla bla bla bla
              bla b bla a_% bla+
              a bla bla bla bla.
------ -------------------------
print_me 0038 bla bla+bla= bla l
              a bla bla +/-blala.
              a bla bla bla blah
              _bla bla bla blaa
              a bla bla bla blaa
              a bla bla bla bla.
------ -------------------------
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please use CODE TAGS {} button to wrap your samples in it and let us know then.

Comment: used CODE TAGS {}

Comment: May be a reference:  https://serverfault.com/questions/391360/remove-line-break-using-awk

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT:*** As per OP there could n number of lines between `-` and actual ones so print all of them following code may help on same.
Let's say following is the sample Input_file:

```
cat Input_file
print_me 0034 bla bla bla bla bl
              a bla bla bla bla.
------ -------------------------
print_me 0035 bla bla bla bla bl
              a bla bla bla bla.
              a bla bla bla bla.
              a bla bla bla bla.
              a bla bla bla bla.
              a bla bla bla bla.
              a bla bla bla bla.
              a bla bla bla bla.
              a bla bla bla bla.
              a bla bla bla bla.
              a bla bla bla bla.
              a bla bla bla bla.
              a bla bla bla bla.
------ -------------------------
print_me 0037 bla bla bla bla bl
              a bla bla bla bla.
------ -------------------------
print_me 0038 bla bla bla bla bl
              a bla bla bla bla.
------ -------------------------
```

Then following is the code which may help on same.

```
awk '/print_me/{print "printername(\047" $2 "\047)";val=$0;sub(/ /,"(",val);getline;while($0!~/^-/){sub(/ +/,"");value=value?value $0:$0;getline};print val value")";val=value=""}'  Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too here.

```
awk '
/print_me/{
  print "printername(\047" $2 "\047)";
  val=$0;
  sub(/ /,"(",val);
  getline;
  while($0!~/^-/){
     sub(/ +/,"");
     value=value?value $0:$0;
     getline};
  print val value")";
  val=value=""
}
'  Input_file
```

---

Following `awk` may help you on same. Which has been made as per your shown sample where it considers that you have only 1 line after `--` line to join.

```
awk '/print_me/{print "printername(\047" $2 "\047)";val=$0;sub(/ /,"(",val);getline;sub(/ +/,"");print val $0")"}'  Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk '
/print_me/{
  print "printername(\047" $2 "\047)";
  val=$0;
  sub(/ /,"(",val);
  getline;
  sub(/ +/,"");
  print val $0")"
}
'   Input_file
```

Comment: This works ! But with a limitation, how can I make this work for unknown number of lines between the pattern '-------' ? I tried a while loop.. couldn't work it.

Comment: @pixie, could you please do let me know sample of it, my code was given as per your sample only, post samples I will provide you code accordingly then.

Comment: @pixie, please check my EDIT code now, I have assumed a Input_file and prepared the code, let me know if this helps you?

Comment: That will spin off into an infinite loop or quietly corrupt the output when getline fails and/or the input is missing a `---` line at the end. See http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline for when it's useful to use getline (it's not in this case since you could just append to `val` in awks normal work loop) and the correct syntax for using it.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for multi-char `RS` (and `\s` and `\S` shorthand for `[[:space:]]` and `[^[:space:]]` respectively since we're using gawk anyway):

```
$ awk -v RS='\n[- ]+\n' '
{
    cmd = $1
    sub(/\S+\s+/,"")
    gsub(/\n\s*/,"")
    printf "printername(\047%s\047)\n%s(%s)\n", $1, cmd, $0
}
' input.txt
printername('0034')
print_me(0034 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.)
printername('0035')
print_me(0035 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.)
printername('0037')
print_me(0037 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.)
printername('0038')
print_me(0038 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.)
```

With other awks it'd be:

```
$ awk '
/^[- ]+$/ {
    $0 = rec
    cmd = $1
    sub(/[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+/,"")
    gsub(/\n[[:space:]]*/,"");
    printf "printername(\047%s\047)\n%s(%s)\n", $1, cmd, $0
    rec = ""
    next
}
{ rec = rec $0 ORS }
' input.txt
```

Note that the ONLY input value being tested above is for the line of dashes that appears at the end of every record (`---...`). It doesn't test for `print_me` or any other text being present within each record so if you have instructions other than `print_me` in the input it'll still work as-is.

Answer (score 0):

If your input is a regular as you show, it's only 3 lines of awk:

```
awk -v q="'" '
    /^-+/ {print ")"; next}
    /^print_me/ {print "printername(" q $2 q ")"; sub(/ /, "(")}
    { gsub(/^[[:blank:]]+/, ""); printf "%s", $0 }
' input2.txt
```

outputs

```
printername('0034')
print_me(0034 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.)
printername('0035')
print_me(0035 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla-a bla bla bla bla.)
printername('0037')
print_me(0037 bla bla bla__la bla bla bla bla blabla b bla a_% bla+a bla bla bla bla.)
printername('0038')
print_me(0038 bla bla+bla= bla la bla bla +/-blala.a bla bla bla blah_bla bla bla blaaa bla bla bla blaaa bla bla bla bla.)
```

Answer (score 0):

With gnu sed

```
sed -E '
  h
  s/([^ ]*) ([^ ]*).*/printername\('"'"'\2'"'"'\)/
  x
  :A
  /\n[- ]+$/bB
  N
  bA
  :B
  s//)/
  y/\n/ /
  s/[[:blank:]][[:blank:]]+/ /g
  s/ /(/
  x
  G
' input2.txt
```